# WPF Binding control with another class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

i would like to know how to bind a textbox to the property of another class. I can bind a property defined in the same class than the **DataContext**. But not to a property defined in a subclass. When i click on the button, only the **label1** is updated. I do not know how to inform the system that Label2 is linked to the property **Class1.Label2**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Label1;
    public string Label1
    {
        get { return _Label1; }
        set
        {
            _Label1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Label1");
        }
    }

    private Class1 objClass1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objClass1 = new Class1();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1 = "foo";
        objClass1.Label2 = "bar";
    }
}
```

**The sub class object**:

```
class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Label2;
    public string Label2
    {
        get { return _Label2; }
        set
        {
            _Label2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Label2");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

**The xaml file :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppBinding2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppBinding2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Label1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Class1.Label2}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="276,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Turn `private Class1 objClass1;` into a property `public Class1 Obj1 { get; }` and write the Binding as `Content="{Binding Path=Obj1.Label2}"`

Comment: In a proper MVVM approach you would move Label1 and Obj1 into a separate "view model" class, and assign the Window's DataContext to an instance of that class, like `DataContext = new ViewModel();`

Comment: Great respect to you thanks a lot.
Yes your right. This is just a fast exemple i made from my full code that respects th MVC design.